# Custom TextBox that accepts only decimals(positive and negative) in WinUI

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

How can I implement a Custom TextBox that accepts only decimals(positive and negative) in WinUI?

Tried implementing Custom TextBox that accepts only decimals(positive and negative) in WinUI but seems like WinUi doesn't have events like that in WPF.

Comment: Do you need to calculate during the input process? For example, input 18*8, output "144"? or just need decimals input? could you describe it in detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT only decimals input and no calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the basics:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace DecimalNumberBoxExample;

public sealed class DecimalNumberBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Value),
        typeof(decimal?),
        typeof(DecimalNumberBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnValuePropertyChanged));

    public DecimalNumberBox()
    {
        BeforeTextChanging += DecimalNumberBox_BeforeTextChanging;
        TextChanging += DecimalNumberBox_TextChanging;
    }

    public decimal? Value
    {
        get => (decimal?)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    private int NextCaretPosition { get; set; }

    private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is DecimalNumberBox decimalNumberBox)
        {
            decimalNumberBox.Text = e.NewValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void DecimalNumberBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        sender.SelectionStart = NextCaretPosition;
    }

    private void DecimalNumberBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewText) is true)
        {
            Value = null;
            return;
        }

        if (decimal.TryParse(args.NewText, out decimal value) is false)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        NextCaretPosition = sender.SelectionStart;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i make it to work with nullable long, if appropriately changed?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to bind it to a long property in a ViewModel? You'll need a ValueConverter.

Comment: I want to create another Custom Textbox which accepts only nullable long, though this code(decimal changed to long) works when given value on UI but initially when my data is coming from backend- it is not binding it on UI

Comment: Did it work? Problem solved?

Comment: Yes, it works if i give the value on UI. But it doesnt pick value when value comes from backend for that property. If possible can you please edit the code which makes it suitable to work with nullable Long

Comment: Also, since my first concern is working fine for decimal values so I have marked it as answer.

Comment: Did you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), or use [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject) NuGet?

Comment: yes, have implemented it. For non nullable long it works totally fine, not sure why this issue only for nullable long.

Comment: Can you post a new question with code in your ViewModel? Don't forget to mention that is an extended question from this post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065213/custom-textbox-to-only-accept-nullable-long-in-wnui

link for the question