# Custom Textbox to only accept nullable long in WinUI

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

This is in extension of issue : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76061104/custom-textbox-that-accepts-only-decimalspositive-and-negative-in-winui?noredirect=1#](https://stackoverflow.com)

I tried creating a Custom textbox that only accepts nullable long values but for the first time when data for that property comes from backend, it brings value(on decoding) in property but doesn't show up on UI else after that it works fine when changing values for it on UI.

ViewModel Code:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace Conversion.Common
{
    public class NullableLongNumberBox : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Value),
            typeof(long?),
            typeof(NullableLongNumberBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnValuePropertyChanged));

        public NullableLongNumberBox()
        {
            BeforeTextChanging += NullableLongNumberBox_BeforeTextChanging;
            TextChanging += NullableLongNumberBox_TextChanging;
        }

        public long? Value
        {
            get => (long?)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        private int NextCaretPosition { get; set; }

        private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is NullableLongNumberBox NullableLongNumberBox)
            {
                NullableLongNumberBox.Text = e.NewValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void NullableLongNumberBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            sender.SelectionStart = NextCaretPosition;
        }

        private void NullableLongNumberBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewText) is true)
            {
                Value = null;
                return;
            }

            if (long.TryParse(args.NewText, out long value) is false)
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            NextCaretPosition = sender.SelectionStart;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml Code:

```
<common:NullableLongNumberBox
    x:Name="longPengeoUpdate"
    Grid.Column="5"
    Width="150"
    Style="{StaticResource NumericTextBoxRightAlignStyle}"
    Value="{Binding PengeoUpdate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `NumberBox` control? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.numberbox?view=winui-2.8

Comment: Or alternatively, use an `x:Bind` with a converter, and put your work in it.

Comment: @Dai The thing with number box is that it accepts double as value so once enter greater than 14-15 digits, it will round off the value which is not acceptable in my case.

Comment: What kind of 15-digit-long values are you having your users enter?

Comment: @Dai 99999999999999

Comment: PengeoUpdate is bound to the control (PengeoUpdate) it self. Is this a typo?

Comment: @SANJEEVPRATAPSingh and what does `99999999999999`  represent in your application, exactly? If it's a placeholder value for no-value then why that value specifically instead of, say, `null`?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding No, actually this control is within a listview so that property is binded to collection's property

Comment: But the ``NullableLongNumberBox`` control is named **PengeoUpdate**, and its value is bound to **PengeoUpdate**.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I have updated it, it was a typo. Also, using non nullable custom control which accepts only long brings the value on the UI with it.

Comment: Can you post code around how you are implementing **PengeoUpdate**?